# Running a Lambda Function immediately before or after Cloudformation ? AWS

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

Looking for some advice on the best approach to launch a Lambda immediately after a cloudformation template stack gets run.

**The use case is:** I run my cloudformation template that setups up An API Gateway with Authorizers, and lambda functions. I then need to get reach out to another SAS/Cloud Service and run some configurations on their side to get everything dialed in.

I was looking into if there is a way to create a Lambda Function with an CloudWatch equivalent of **Now**, so it will launch immediately and do any finishing work that might need to be done.

I don't imagine I am the only person who might need to do this type of configuration. I could use multiple Cloudformation Scripts, but I'm trying to simply this for others who might not have much AWS experience, and **Automate** as much as possible. The more I can do in Amazon, the less scripting someone else might have to do.

If anyone has any ideas, or I missed something basic stuff, please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take a look at [AWS CloudFormation Custom Resources](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-cfn-customresource.html). From the docs:

> Custom resources provide a way for you to write custom provisioning logic in AWS CloudFormation template and have AWS CloudFormation run it during a stack operation, such as when you create, update or delete a stack.

With this custom resource you can call a Lambda function by handing over its ARN to the custom resource. See also [this doc article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/template-custom-resources.html) for more background information.

Note: I haven't tried it by myself, but it seems to be the right thing for you.

Comment: Thank you, that did fire a Lambda function after it was created. Awesome.

Comment: I just added this to the end of my SAM Template

  DeploymentCustomResource:
    Type: Custom::AppConfiguration
    Properties:
      ServiceToken: !GetAtt HelloLambda99.Arn